# explain this piece of code please

Tags: java

Ok here is the code to get the maximum of an array as you can see,but I have a bit of problem understanding what this would return ,

```
public static double getMaximum(double[][] list) {

        double max = -100000000000.0;
        int idxmax  = 0;
        for(int i=0;i<list.length;i++) {
            if(list[i][1]>max) {
                max = list[i][1];
                idxmax=i;
            }
        }
        return list[idxmax][0];
}
```

Comment: Show us a sample of the argument `list` and what you get as the result.

Comment: This won't work, since i believe you to get an index out of bounds exception

Comment: @jbutler483  it works, this is not the full code, its a part of a main

Comment: hellojava: please see RealSkeptic's answer in relation to why I (also) believe this code to contain errors

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/27381509/edit), don't put code in comments.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you have a list like:

```
id    value
1     456
2     078
3     347
4     484
5     9520
6     456
```

it would return the id `5`, since it's corresponding value is the largest in the list.

Answer (score 2):

Given an array of arrays, where all of the rows arrays have at least two column, it returns the value of the first column, of the row that had the biggest second column.

If any of the rows inside the array have less than two columns, you will get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` thrown.

Also, if all of the rows have a number that is smaller than `-1e12`, you'll get the first column of the first row.

And if the array is empty, again you will get `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`

Answer (score 0):

It perform a test on all `list[i][1]` elements to find the index of the maximal value (stored in idxmax).

Then it return `list[idxmax][0]`.

So it return the element `(list[idxmax][0])` associated with the maximal value in the list `list[i][1]`.